# Driving my expat parents' car in the UK

Tags: driving, vehicle-registration

So here's the situation. My parents live in Germany, and own an LHD, German registered car there, on which I am insured. I live in the UK.

Our understanding is that I can drive my parents in their car from East Germany all across to Calais, but I'm not allowed to drive the last hour or so on the English side, since I am a UK resident attempting to drive a non-UK car. Is that correct, or does my not owning the car, and the car only "visiting" change the situation?

Comment: Where do you get that understanding from?  Do your parents' insurance company think you are insured to drive the car in England? (Ask them.)

Answer (score 1):

This [UK Government webpage](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk) and a slew of other SE answers confirm that as a UK resident, you cannot enter the UK with an EU vehicle. EU (and perhaps other) cars can be brought into the UK by tourists for up to 6 months, but UK residents cannot do this.

Comment: OTOH, if the parents are in the car when it is driven into the UK, I think the OP can still *drive* the car in the UK.

Comment: Perhaps if the parents are *driving* the car it'd work, but I wouldn't bet on it. and I really wouldn't want to be the OP if he's caught driving the car in the UK without his parents.